# How to wait untill all the url complete and throw success msg nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want all url to complete first then throw success message. But here in my code success message always come when a page completed. There are more than 2000 pages of website i want to grab.

```
  function makeRequest(pageNo){
    if(pageNo < 1) {
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        request('http://www.mudah.my/malaysia/cars-for-sale?o='+pageNo+1+'&q=&th=1', function(err, res, body) {
            if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                var links = [];
                $('.list_ads').not('.honey-pot').each(function () {
                    links.push($(this).find('.listing_ads_params a').attr('href'));
                });
                async.eachSeries(links, function(uri, next){
                    console.log('i will go this '+uri);
                    next();
                }, function(callback){
                    console.log('All Url Done;');
                });
            }
        });
        makeRequest(pageNo-1);
    }, 1000);
}

makeRequest(2522);
```

How to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should use thread. nodejs is a single thread app. but with some modules you can create multiple thread on nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but looking at your code, you first want to grab page 2522. After that you parse it to look for ad links in there, and visit each of these urls. When you visited all those urls on the page, you want to go to the next page.

Does this sound like what you want to achieve? If so, you should place the new call to `makeRequest()` in the callback function from `async.eachSeries`. A bit like this:

For extra speed, you could try to use a multiple thread module for nodejs, so you can run the page requests simultaneously, but I will leave that to you to figure that out :)

```
var pageNo = 2522;

function makeRequest(){
    request('http://www.mudah.my/malaysia/cars-for-sale?o='+pageNo+'&q=&th=1', function(err, res, body) {
        if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var links = [];
            $('.list_ads').not('.honey-pot').each(function () {
                links.push($(this).find('.listing_ads_params a').attr('href'));
            });
            async.eachSeries(links, function(uri, next){
                next();
            }, function(){
                if(--pageNo > 0) {
                    makeRequest();
                } else {
                   console.log("all done");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

makeRequest();
```